# Free duplicate music finder for Mac

Tags: macos, itunes, mp3

I'm trying to clean up an mp3 folder which has a plethora of duplicate files in it due to accidentally dragging my music folder into iTunes and having it re-import songs which were already in the play list.

I tried writing a quick Python app to md5 all of the files, and delete exact duplicates.  This took out ~2gb of files.  Unfortunately, however, this does not work on all of the duplicates because of an iTunes feature.  iTunes has changed the ID3 `title` on some of the duplicate songs, which means the md5 of the entire file is different from the same song with a different ID3 tag.

Are there any free applications out there (for the mac) which can compare the data of the actual song (ignoring ID3 tags) and determine if duplicates exist?

Comment: Does iTunes handle library management, and copies the files over when you add them?

Comment: Yes, it does copy them over.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps you could use iTunes itself?

If you sort your music collection by 'date added' you should be able to undo the accidental re-import.

In case that column is not visible (I think it's not on by default), go to "Content -> View options..." in the menu bar and make sure the box for "Date added" is ticked. Now the column we're looking for should be visible, go ahead and click the column header to sort the library by it.

At the very least, this should give you the option of deleting the entire re-import and start over again (the most recently added tracks should appear at the top).

---

PS. The menu options quoted above are rough translations, I'm on a Swedish mac.

Comment: iTunes is quite capable of doing the job. I have used it for this myself.